# How to read a mapping through devtools

Tags: javascript, mapping

I'm working on [Ethernaut challenge lvl 1](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9CB391dbcD447E645D6Cb55dE6ca23164130D008)

follow the link or scroll below for the smartcontract code.

I check my addresse in the "contributions" mapping, I add some eth, and I recheck.

what are thoses numbers ?
24035328, 4470348
32047104, 5960464

where is my deposit amount ?

(and what is this "weird" parameter, "red" ?)

[image: img]

here's the smartcontract below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract Fallback {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint) public contributions;
  address payable public owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    contributions[msg.sender] = 1000 * (1 ether);
  }

  modifier onlyOwner {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "caller is not the owner"
        );
        _;
    }

  function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value < 0.001 ether);
    contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    if(contributions[msg.sender] > contributions[owner]) {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }
  }

  function getContribution() public view returns (uint) {
    return contributions[msg.sender];
  }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  receive() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0 && contributions[msg.sender] > 0);
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, understood a lof of things :

- Javascript doesn't handle very big numbers. Usually web3 devs uses https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/. That's why https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#towei requires string or BN format
- If I enter to.Wei("0.0001"), that means 100 000 000 000 000 wei, and it's handled in a quirk way by js because of the first point.

If I just push await contract.contribute({value: 1}), the value handled in the mapping is 1.

With some examples, I understood that
await contract.contribute({value: 99999999})
is stored with [32891135, 1] in the mapping, appearing that js is storing
99999999 = 99 999 999 = 32 891 135 + 2^26 x 1

Everything is clear rn.

Comment: Except the red parameter :/